# Why we need Ouroboros BFT as a migration phase from Ouroboros Classic to Ouroboros Genesis?

Tags: cardano

Re https://youtu.be/vgfTHVWaNCY

Why we need to have interoperability layer between Ouroboros Classic and Ouroboros Genesis in form of Ouroboros BFT?

Why not just discontinue all Ouroboros Classic nodes and switch right to Ouroboros Genesis? (Iohk owns them all anyway, because cardano not released yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current codebase is been deprecated and two new are already in development (in Rust and Haskell). For the sake of speed, it’s way easier to implement Ouroboros Genesis + OBFT rather than Ouroboros Genesis + Ouroboros Classic (with the specific technical decision already made in the old repository).

Comment: Yes, understand, it's good to have OBFT anyway for development and testing, because it's fast though centralized